# How to add a particular character to a string in VB script?

Tags: html, string, vbscript

I have a string 2014. I want to add a . (dot)  after 1st character. So that result will be 2.014 .

How to achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
' Assuming str = "2014"
Mid(str, 1, 1) & "." & Mid(str, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^(\d)(\d+)"

s = "2014"
WScript.Echo re.Replace(s, "$1.$2")
```